# Why do we specify size_t array size in C rather than just using integers? And what are the advantages to do so?

Tags: arrays, c, size-t

I am starting to learn C and one of my homework exercises requires me to create an array
`size_t const N_MAX = 10; double v1[N_MAX];` 
I understand that size_t represents the v1 array length but I still don't get what the size_t type contributes here rather than using an int N_MAX?

Comment: Do you need to get the array size later in your program? For example to iterate (loop) over the array? Perhaps when all you have is a *pointer* to its first element? Then you need some other way to specify the size, like having a named constant instead of using a [*magic number*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). In C macros are mostly used for this rather than `const` variables (since a `const` variable in C isn't really a compile-time constant, but just a variable whose value can't be modified).

Comment: `size_t` is an alias for an `unsigned` type. Which means it can't go negative. It should be used for - what the name implies - sizes.

Comment: When you have a 64-bit pointer, then a 32-bit `int` may not be large enough to represent the size of the object which is pointed to.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to clarify what you're really asking? Are you asking about the use of using the variable `N_MAX`? Or are you asking why it need to be a `size_t` rather than plain `int`? Or perhaps something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> size_t can store the maximum size of a theoretically possible object
> of any type (including array).
>
> size_t is commonly used for array indexing and loop counting. Programs
> that use other types, such as unsigned int, for array indexing may
> fail on, e.g. 64-bit systems when the index exceeds UINT_MAX or if it
> relies on 32-bit modular arithmetic.

([source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t))

What this means is that `size_t` is guaranteed to be able to hold any size/index count on any platform you compile for.

It is usually defined based on the target platform you compile for. For example the `intsafe.h` header included in the Windows SDK defines it as follows:

```c
#ifdef _WIN64
typedef __int64             ptrdiff_t;
typedef unsigned __int64    size_t;
#else
typedef int            ptrdiff_t;
typedef unsigned int   size_t;
#endif
```

Using `size_t` directly means that you don't have to worry about changing the data type you use for indexing or holding object sizes when you recompile for a different architecture (for example, x86 vs x86-64).

EDIT: As @Eric Postpischil mentions in the comments, that actual wording of the C standard is different from the explanation I linked from cppreference.

Looking at [the standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf) we can see a few mentions regarding `size_t`:

> 6.5.3.4 The sizeof and alignof operators
>
> [...]
>
> 5 The value of the result of both operators is implementation-defined,
> and its type (an unsigned integer type) is size_t, defined in
> <stddef.h> (and other headers)
>
> [...]
>
> 7.19 Common definitions <stddef.h>
>
> [...]
>
> size_t
> which is the unsigned integer type of the result of the sizeof operator;

The fact that `size_t` is the type of the value returned by the `sizeof` operator is the reason for which we can assume that "size_t can store the maximum size of a theoretically possible object of any type", but nowhere in the standard is this actually mandated. The standard also says the following about `sizeof`:

> The sizeof operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which
> may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The size is
> determined from the type of the operand. The result is an integer. If
> the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand
> is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result
> is an integer constant

My **interpretation** (which may be wrong) is that you can't have an object for which the size does not fit into a `size_t` because in that case you can't have a working `sizeof` operator.

EDIT 2:

I'll just quote Eric Postpischil here:

> There are simply limits as to what we can do with computers, and
> sometimes calculations go out of bounds. It is generally easy on
> modern hardware to define size_t so that sizeof always works, and you
> obviously cannot malloc a larger object, but you might construct one
> with a static array, in some esoteric C implementation with 16-bit
> size_t but 22-bit addresses.

Comment: @Some programmer dude I'm not sure I understand your comment. That's what I said: you don't have to worry about the right data type for object sizes when you compile your sources for another platform (for example, x86 vs x86_64).

Comment: Oh, I see how that can be misleading. I edited my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Re “`size_t` is guaranteed…”: The C standard does not guarantee this. The intent is undoubtedly that `size_t` is suitable for sizes and can hold the size of any object when that is possible in the C implementation, but all the standard says about it is that `size_t` is “the unsigned integer type of the result of the `sizeof` operator”. cppreference.com has been found to have a number of errors, and it is certainly not an authoritative source for the C or C++ standards.

Comment: Re “… in that case you can't have a working `sizeof` operator”: Many of the operators have values for which they do not work. For example, `*` fails in `INT_MAX * INT_MAX`. This is addressed in C 2018 5.2.4: There are simply limits as to what we can do with computers, and sometimes calculations go out of bounds. It is generally easy on modern hardware to define `size_t` so that `sizeof` always works, and you obviously cannot `malloc` a larger object, but you might construct one with a static array, in some esoteric C implementation with 16-bit `size_t` but 22-bit addresses.

Comment: (I do not think this potential `size_t` limitation is at all likely these days, but I think it is good for students to keep in mind the fact that all programming languages have a variety of limitations. If they are just aware that the bounds are there, somewhere, they are less likely to bump into them by mistake someday. Given today’s plentiful computing resources, it is easy to lose oneself in the abstract model of an idealized computer and forget there are bounds.)

Comment: "you might construct one with a static array, in some esoteric C implementation with 16-bit size_t but 22-bit addresses." I completely failed to consider this case. My 16-bit experience is limited and comes only from assembly. I added your example to my answer. I hope you don't mind the direct quote.